# Batch file ping once every minute

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I got this bat file from Stackoverflow that someone had posted back in 2014 but it will not output any info to the filename?

The file is created but without any info.....

can anyone please help, trying to record the ping output every 1 minute on a windows 7 machine.

```
@ECHO off
set IPADDRESS=192.168.0.1
set INTERVAL=60
:PINGINTERVAL
ping %IPADDRESS% -n 1 >> filename.txt
timeout %INTERVAL%
GOTO PINGINTERVAL
```

Comment: http://superuser.com/

Comment: Try taking off the `@ECHO off` to see what it's doing.

Comment: It just outputs the following: :\Users\user\Desktop>set IPADDRESS=192.168.4.254 

C:\Users\user\Desktop>set INTERVAL=60 

C:\Users\user\Desktop>ping 192.168.4.254 -n 1  1>>filename.txt 

C:\Users\user\Desktop>set IPADDRESS=192.168.4.254 

C:\Users\user\Desktop>set INTERVAL=60 

C:\Users\user\Desktop>ping 192.168.4.254 -n 1  1>>filename.txt 

C:\Users\user\Desktop>set IPADDRESS=192.168.4.254 

C:\Users\user\Desktop>set INTERVAL=60

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/345214/how-can-i-perform-a-ping-every-x-minutes-and-check-the-response-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your batch file is called `ping.bat` or `ping.cmd` and is calling itself. Rename the batch file or replace `ping %IPADDRESS% ...` with `ping.exe %IPADDRESS% ...`

Answer (score 0):

The "echo off" is ok. This will only omit output from the script, not from the "ping" app.

I think the output is created in an unexpected location. Add the following lines at the beginning of the script to verify the current folder.

@echo %cd% 
pause

Or simply specify the full path like so: 
  >> d:\fullpath\filename.txt